# The below 2 sets of codes, one of them works and the other does not. can someone help me undertand why

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

toDoList is an array with some objects with propeties

This one does not work. It returns undefined.

```
const showToDo = toDoList.filter((todo)=>todo.isDone === true);
const showToDoTitle = showToDo.forEach(todo=>todo.title);

console.log(showToDoTitle);
```

This one works

```
const showToDo = toDoList.filter((todo)=>todo.isDone === true);
showToDoTitle = showToDo.forEach(todo=>console.log(todo.title));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach` doesn't return anything.

The second one works because `console.log()` prints the title within the `.forEach` function.
If you were to add `console.log(showToDoTitle)` in the second example, you'd *also* get a `undefined` printed.